# Import Discontiguous Excel Columns to Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

[image]

strRange = "C:C,H:H,J:J,S:S,AA:AA"

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet , cSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "tbl_adds", strInputFileName, True, stRange
```

The spreadsheet in question has 40 columns of which I only need 5 (listed in stRange)

Is this a syntax thing or do I have to use a different method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't import but *link* the worksheet.

Create a simple *select query* with the linked table as source. In this, mark the five columns in question and save the query.

Now use this query for your import.

Comment: Thank you Gustav ... much more controllable and clean method.